# Coveo load more functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, coveo

I am trying to implement "Load more" functionality instead the basic pagination in Coveo.
My button code is below. Only the console logs work, the code don't send ajax to the service.

I have searched the Coveo documentation for load more button/functions but didn't find any.

```
//html code of button    
<div data-firstres="0" class="load_more_btn">Load More</div>     

//js
$('.load_more_btn').on('click', function() {
    var this_btn = $(this);
    var firstResult = this_btn.attr('data-firstres');
    var q = $('.magic-box-input input').val();
    console.log(q);
    var new_res = parseInt(firstResult) + 10;
    this_btn.attr('data-firstres', new_res);
    console.log(new_res);
    var root = document.body;
    Coveo.SearchEndpoint.endpoints['default'] = new Coveo.SearchEndpoint({
      restUri: 'https://platform.cloud.coveo.com/rest/search',
      queryStringArguments: {
          organizationId: 'replaced_val',
          numberOfResults: '10',
          firstResult:firstResult,
          q:q
        },
      accessToken: acc_token,
    });
    Coveo.init(root);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

displayMoreResults worked for me

```
$('.load_more_btn').on('click', function() {
  Coveo.$('.CoveoResultList').coveo('displayMoreResults', 5);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your code will not fill your required behavior.

`Coveo.init` should only be called once, it is used to initialize the search interface. The `SearchEndpoint` should only be set once, before the initialization, and not after each "LoadMore" click.

You should then alter the query using [JavaScript Search Events](https://docs.coveo.com/en/417/javascript-search-framework/javascript-search-framework-events) and [JavaScript API calls](https://coveo.github.io/search-ui/).

So for your use case, you can leverage the [displayMoreResults method](https://coveo.github.io/search-ui/components/resultlist.html#displaymoreresults) of the `CoveoResultList` component.

You can also follow the exampel of the [ShowMore](https://github.com/coveo-labs/search-ui-custom-components/blob/master/src/components/ShowMore/ShowMore.ts) custom component created by Coveo people in the [JavaScript Search Framework Custom Components repository](https://github.com/coveo-labs/search-ui-custom-components). Here is the relevant part of the `displayMoreResults()` method being called by the custom component:

```
public loadMore() {
  this.resultList ? this.resultList.displayMoreResults(this.options.count || 10) : null;
}

public get resultList(): ResultList | null {
  const resultListElement = $$(this.root).find('.CoveoResultList');
  if (resultListElement) {
    return get(resultListElement) as ResultList;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I have added
`Coveo.$$(root).on("buildingQuery", function(e, args) {
        queryBuilder = args.queryBuilder;
        queryBuilder.firstResult = 22;
    });`
upon init, and
`Coveo.state(root).attributes.first = 22;
    Coveo.executeQuery(root);`
in the load more click event
but still didn't change the query, it always runs with default parameters.

Comment: This is not what I explained up here, you must use the `displayMoreResults` call, or take the ShowMore component as an example for a full framework component.